# eclipse 2023-03 m2 version cannot run in debug mode normally

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I've downloaded eclipse 2023-03 m2 version for a few days, and I found that my application cannot run in debug mode anymore, the console log said:

*
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jdt/launching/internal/javaagent/Premain: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0*

when it run normally with version eclipse 2022-09, I am ensure that all my eclipse configurations are set rightly, include jdk6、compile jdk1.6 and tomcat6. Hope anyone can do me a favor catch the point.

thanks.

I've tried find the answer in search engine and found nothing.

I'm expecting the eclipse 2023-03 m2 can run in debug mode normally as 2022-09.

Comment: Note 2023-03M2 was a milestone release intended only for testing, it has already been made obsolete by 2023-03RC2. The final release of 2023-03 will be on 15th March.

Answer (score 1):

"Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 " means that the mentioned class was compiled for Java 1.7, and can not be used with older versions of Java. If you want to debug with modern releases of Eclipse, you'll need to do it by launching Tomcat with Java 1.7 so that the Eclipse classes are understood.

As an aside, Tomcat 6 and Java 1.6 have both been out of support for over 4 years. Neither is being patched for bugs or security issues. You should upgrade to releases that are supported.